# Why the load factor is set to 1 in Redis dict

Tags: hash, redis, hashmap

As we know that in hash table, load factor is important for controlling conflict.

> In Java/HashMap, the default load factor is **0.75**, And in CPython/dict, the load factor is set to **[2 / 3](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L159)**

However, in Redis/dict, it is **[1.0](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/dict.c#L954)** (when dict_can_resize is enabled), why?

```
/* If we reached the 1:1 ratio, and we are allowed to resize the hash
 * table (global setting) or we should avoid it but the ratio between
 * elements/buckets is over the "safe" threshold, we resize doubling
 * the number of buckets. */
if (d->ht[0].used >= d->ht[0].size &&
    (dict_can_resize ||
     d->ht[0].used/d->ht[0].size > dict_force_resize_ratio))
{
    return dictExpand(d, d->ht[0].used*2);
}
```

In my view, load factor should be less than **1**. A high load factor might increase the lookup cost due to the possible highly conflict rate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A high load factor is also more memory-efficient. Redis is an in-memory database, it needs to be memory-efficient. I think the author of Redis has done some benchmark test to balance the memory usage and performance.

Comment: Sorry, for the reason why redis load factor is 1, I think your answer is not ideal.